# Почему я могу использовать данный код только один раз?

Tags: java, android

```
String get_words_from_file(){
        String text = "words";
        byte[] buffer = null;
        InputStream is;
        try {
            is = getAssets().open(text);
            int size = is.available();
            buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String str_data = new String(buffer);
        return str_data;
    }
```

Попытки использовать его ещё раз вызывают ошибку 'android.content.res.AssetManager android.content.Context.getAssets()' on a null object reference

Comment: что значит вызвать еще раз? как вы вызываете повторно?

Comment: Создаю объект класса и вызываю данный метод, чтобы получить содержимое файла из assets

Comment: Можете Ваш вопрос дополнить этим? Например, так? `for(;;){ get_words_from_file (); }` ?

Answer (score 0):

У вас в объект is приходит ссылка на нулевой объект. Т.е. ваша функция повторно вызванная возвращает null(объект повторно не создается почему-то). Не плохо было бы дополнить код функцией getAssets() не понятно, что она возвращает.